# Make: Totally ignoring a rule

Tags: c, linux, gcc, makefile

I am trying to compile my project after adding a new source(processHandling.c) and I am getting this as a result when I 'make'

```
gcc -gstabs -W -Wall -std=gnu99 -c main.c
gcc -gstabs -W -Wall -std=gnu99 -c inputHandling.c
gcc -gstabs -W -Wall -std=gnu99 -c syscallsWrapper.c
gcc -gstabs -W -Wall -std=gnu99 -o myShell main.o inputHandling.o processHandling.o syscallsWrapper.o 
gcc: error: processHandling.o: No such file or directory
make: *** [myShell] Error 1
```

This is the makefile

```
CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -gstabs -W -Wall -std=gnu99

myShell: main.o inputHandling.o syscallsWrapper.o
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o myShell main.o inputHandling.o processHandling.o syscallsWrapper.o 


main.o: main.c
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c main.c

inputHandling.o: inputHandling.c
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c inputHandling.c

processHandling.o: processHandling.c
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c processHandling.c

syscallsWrapper.o: syscallsWrapper.c
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c syscallsWrapper.c

clean:

        -rm myShell *.o
```

I tried running make with the `-d` flag and it seems make for some reason is totally ignoring the rule to compile `processHandling.o`; what could the problem be?

Also note that if I compile processHandling manually using `gcc -c` everything works fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add processHandling.o to the dependency list for the myShell target:

```
myShell: main.o inputHandling.o processHandling.o syscallsWrapper.o
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o myShell main.o inputHandling.o processHandling.o syscallsWrapper.o
```

By the way, using [automatic variables](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Automatic-Variables) can help reduce the repeated file names. For example:

```
myShell: main.o inputHandling.o processHandling.o syscallsWrapper.o
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $^
```

Comment: BTW: you can avoid a lot of this kind of errors by using a list : `OBJS=main.o inputHandling.o processHandling.o syscallsWrapper.o`, and then referring to $OBJS in the two lines that need them.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add "processHandling.o" as a prerequisit of myShell. Otherwise when making myShell, the rule for processHandling.o will not be applied because the makefile thinks that that processHandling.o is not needed for myShell. You can simply add it like this

```
myShell: main.o inputHandling.o syscallsWrapper.o processHandling.o
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o myShell main.o inputHandling.o processHandling.o syscallsWrapper.o
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if you really have the file `processHandling.c`. This error implies that the source file has not been found.